# Alternative chain shows blocks with empty TXIDs - what's going on?

Tags: transactions, litecoin, transaction-id

An alternative chain based on Litecoin 0.8.6.1 that I have an interest in is during certain low-difficulty periods showing several blocks that contain empty TXIDs. Digging into the TXIDs return nothing with gettxout, and "No info available" with getrawtransaction. Usually these blocks contain just a single empty TXID, but some blocks can contain normal TXIDs as well as an empty one.

What's the cause of this? What action can create these empty blocks with no apparent transaction or coinbase content in them? Can it be rectified?

Answer (score 1):

maybe client is not indexing the transactions.

I'm having this problem and apparently running yourcoind -txindex (or txindex=1 in the conf)  and afterwards run with -reindex will fix the issue

when I run this command it just hangs but it looks like it's actually doing something which might take a long time. I may have to start from scratch with those changes added first